# What makes this question on-topic?

Tags: discussion

What makes [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/23959/1046) on-topic on networkengineering.stackexchange.com?

I'm asking because so far I felt that NE.SE is mostly about low-level networking concepts and/or professional network technologies and this question seems to be about neither.

Answer (score 1):

In the comments, your original assertion was that you had similar questions "blocked in the past."

Looking at the history of your questions, you had one that was closed for being a home networking question and two that were asking about the operation of SPDY.

In response, you said you thought they were similar because "they cover an application-layer protocol."

So, let's look at your two SPDY question titles (I won't link them as they are deleted and won't be viewable by most members of the community).

- Why are the headers of this SPDY SYN_STREAM sample apparently uncompressed?
- Where is SPDY/HTTP2 server hinting defined?

In both these cases you are asking about details regarding the application layer protocol, and a protocol which has nothing to do with networking in general (not routing, IP, etc). It is purely an application level protocol used by applications.

In the case of [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/23959/33), it is not a question *about* application protocols. It is at it's heart a question about the requirements of a network/security policy and why such a policy would have such a requirement.

Implementation and enforcement of network/security policies is directly in line with the types of questions that face network professionals.

Answer (score 1):

I think the question doesn't really fall off-topic because it doesn't ask how an application layer protocol works, or how an application is configured to use it.

It *may* have been a question better asked of the employer, but the question wasn't overly broad and there was a clear and obvious answer; the question didn't lead to opinion-based answers.

I can't view your questions, but, if as YLearn writes, they were home networking or questions about the operation of an application layer protocol, they were specifically off-topic.